# Coinbase Pro Example Query

Tags: coinbase-api

**What resources to use writing a Coinbase Pro Client ??**

I'm trying to write an example Coinbase Pro client e.g. lists all your wallets and transactions.

- This Example I'm not sure how to handle / decode the API-Secret https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication
  When placing the the API_KEY and API_SECRET as plain text I get the error
  `raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)`
  `TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'`
- Then there is a very similar link But looks more like JavaScript https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/authorization-and-authentication
- Other tutorials e.g. [Coinbase Pro API – An Introductory Guide](https://algotrading101.com/learn/coinbase-pro-api-guide/)
  using completly different libraries..

**So what is a good starting point / tutorial to access coinbase pro** 
coinbase I managed and it was super easy :)

Comment: You linked to the docs that tell how to sign an authenticated request so... what exactly is your question here? it would be helpful if you show your code that causes the error, not just the error.

Comment: I use exaclty the code from the link in the question

Answer (score 0):

Some light into the questions:

1. still in research
2. still in research - probably not relevant
3. The tutorial talks about the coinbase pro API - BUT it uses / calls methods of [coinbasepro-python wrapper](https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python) which internally calls the api.